What is the purpose of ServiceFilterAttribute IsReusable property?
What is the purpose of ServiceFilterAttribute.IsReusable property ? See link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.servicefilterattribute.isreusable?view=aspnetcore-6.0
I understand that TypeFilterAttribute needs it so that once we set it to true instance of the filter can be re-used across requests. But in case of filters set using ServiceFilterAttribute it doesnt makes sense, because you already register the filter in .net core DI system as either Singleton, Scoped or Transient which would specify whether one or multiple instance of the filter will exist.

"because you already register the filter in .net core DI system as either Singleton, Scoped or Transient which would specify whether one or multiple instance of the filter will exist." - Singleton in DI is just one specific kind of singleton. Just because something is a DI Singleton doesn't mean it's an OOP Singleton, or non-singleton-but-please-reuse-me-whereever-possible.
